# In Highstock v1.3.1 is there a way to detect setExtremes only on mouse up?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to load new data for a stock chart in highstock 1.3.1, and I only want to make the call to load new data when the navigator's extremes have been set (on mouse up), not when the user is dragging the navigator buttons. Currently setExtremes and afterSetExtremes both seem to trigger on mouse move. Is there another built in event I can bind to?

Comment: Taka a look `Selection`. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.selection

Comment: Selection only seems to work for the main chart, not the navigator.

Comment: You can disable [liveRedraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.liveRedraw) so afterSetExtremes will be called only after mouseUp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable [liveRedraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.liveRedraw) so afterSetExtremes will be called only after mouseUp.

Comment: Additionally the highcharts guys added additional data to the setExtremes event so you can see which mouse event triggered it: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/a2ba8f046c84a39dd362049c09a0aa0995b4d2c3

Answer (score 0):

So the answer seems to be disabling liveRedraw for the scrollbar, which makes very little sense as the scrollbar is disabled in my chart, and then binding to the setExtremes event. So my chart options object looks something like:

```
var chart_options = {
                      chart: {...}
                      scrollbar: {
                        enabled: false,
                        liveRedraw: false
                      },
                      xAxis: {
                        events: {
                          setExtremes: setExtremesHandler()
                        }
                      }
                     };
```

@Pawel Fus - you really deserve the credit for this answer, so if you post a proper answer rather than a comment, I'll  mark it as the solution. Thanks.